# Is there a way to convert a natural language date NSString to an NSDate

Tags: objective-c, ios, parsing, nlp, nsdate

Say I have the NSString `@"tomorrow"`

Is there any library that takes strings such as this and converts them into NSDates? I'm imagining/hoping for something like this:

```
NSString* humanDate = @"tomorrow at 4:15";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"x at HH:MM"];
NSDate* date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:humanDate];
```

I would also want to do things like "Next monday", etc. but it doesn't have to be super sophisticated. I can enforce rules on input, but I'd like a little bit of natural language available.

My alternative is to take the string, break it up into pieces, and format it manually. But I was hoping someone has already done this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean something like [dateWithNaturalLanguageString:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDate/dateWithNaturalLanguageString%3a)?

From the link:

> dateWithNaturalLanguageString:
>
> Creates and returns an NSDate object set to the date and time specified by a given string.
>
> + (id)dateWithNaturalLanguageString:(NSString *)string
>
> A string that contains a colloquial specification of a date, such as “last Tuesday at     dinner,” “3pm December 31, 2001,” “12/31/01,” or “31/12/01.”

Comment: This is considered private API use, isn't it? It's not documented in NSDate for iOS and it produces a warning. It works, though.

Comment: -1 if you submit an app to the iOS App Store with this, **it will probably be rejected**.  `+dateWithNaturalLanguageString:` is private API on iOS.

Comment: @Dave, in that case, any other suggestions?

Comment: For anyone seeing this now, this method is no longer private. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDate/dateWithNaturalLanguageString:

Comment: dateWithNaturalLanguageString is now deprecated since iOS10, but you can use https://github.com/kevinlawler/NSDate-TimeAgo

Comment: If your case cover only few limited natural language pattern, just parse it by yourself. if not, you can try this https://github.com/quire-io/SwiftyChrono.