# NSDate Syntax Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

The section of code show below produces an error message. The problem is located at the line that begins with "NSDate    *startDate  = [NSDate .....

The error I am getting is "Class method '+dateWithNaturalLanguageString:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')

Any help with this issue would be appreciated.

---

```
    if ((value3 > 0))  {
            // NSLog(@"Maturity Date field is populated"); 

            temp44 = enterSettleDateField.text;
            temp11 = enterMatDateField.text;

            NSDate *today = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
            NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
            [dateFormat setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
```

(Problem Here)

```
    NSDate   *startDate  = [NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString: temp44], *endDate  = [NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString: temp11];

            NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                                     initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

            NSUInteger unitFlags = NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;

            NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:unitFlags
                                                        fromDate:startDate
                                                          toDate:endDate options:0];

            NSInteger months = [components month];
            NSInteger days = [components day];

            temp13 = ( (float) months / 12);            // cast integer to float
            temp14 = ( (float) days / 364);
            temp15 = (temp13 + temp14);
            temp4 = temp15;

            [gregorian release];

        }
```

Comment: That's a method on the Mac, but not in iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That class method is available on OS X, but not on iOS. It [actually *does* exist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5887617/1849664) on iOS, but it's considered private, and your app will be rejected if you try to submit it to the App Store using this method.

You're going to have to find a third party library to accomplish this on iOS.

Comment: While I now agree that the class method in question is a OS X method, I did submit the above code and it was accepted by Apple and worked in my iPhone app for over five years.  But you suggestion got me headed into the right area of Date Formatters for iOS and I change my code to the following: From -    NSDate  *startDate  = [NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString: temp44], *endDate  = [NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString: temp11];  (Comment Out)
    
 TO -           NSDate *startDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:temp44];
                NSDate *endDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:temp11];